# I can set up an arm64 docker image, but can't run anything

Tags: docker, x86-64, qemu, arm64

I have a CentOS 7 x86_64 virtual machine. I need to do some things in an Oracle Linux 8 arm64 docker container.

I installed docker and qemu:

```
$ sudo yum install -y yum-utils
$ sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo 
$ sudo yum install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin \
 qemu-system-arm qemu qemu-user qemu-kvm qemu-kvm-tools libvirt virt-install \
 libvirt-python libguestfs-tools-c
```

I then started docker and set up qemu-user-static:

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
$ docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM oraclelinux:8.5
ENV container docker
RUN dnf -y install sssd nscd unzip zip xz which file
RUN useradd --uid 1001 -ms /bin/bash cm
RUN uname -m
```

Then created x86_64 and arm64 images using the following:

```
docker buildx create --name ol8_builder
docker buildx --builder ol8_builder build -t frickson/oracle8 . --platform=linux/amd64 --load --progress=plain
docker buildx --builder ol8_builder build -t frickson/oracle8arm . --platform=linux/arm64 --load --progress=plain
```

During the build on both images, the `RUN useradd` works and the user is created. The `RUN uname -m` works on both systems, producing the correct output (`x86_64` and `aarch64` respectively).

The x86_64 machine works correctly:

```
$ docker run --rm --privileged frickson/oracle8 uname -m
x86_64
```

But the arm64 machine does not:

```
$ docker run --platform linux/arm64 --rm --privileged frickson/oracle8arm uname -a
exec /usr/bin/uname: no such file or directory
```

I'm guessing it's not finding one or more libraries, since it worked during the image build. Trying to run any command (`bash`, `ls`, `true`) all result in the same error message.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Thanks!

EDIT: In response to @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica:

It didn't work. And I don't have access to an ARM host to check my image.

```
$ sudo docker run --platform linux/arm64 -it --rm --privileged oraclelinux:8 /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'oraclelinux:8' locally
8: Pulling from library/oraclelinux
e12ce518ed4b: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:cad3a3dc2dd9f03dec02642dce1f194562e7f21820bc36ceb9f7b070d337fb45
Status: Downloaded newer image for oraclelinux:8
exec /bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Comment: To narrow down the problem, can you try these two things? 1. See if the `oraclelinux:8` ARM image from Docker Hub works on your VM. 2. See if the `zyprotect/oracle8arm` image that you built works on a real ARM host

Comment: ```$ sudo docker run --platform linux/arm64 -it --rm --privileged oraclelinux:8 /bin/bash

Unable to find image 'oraclelinux:8' locally

8: Pulling from library/oraclelinux

e12ce518ed4b: Pull complete 

Digest: sha256:cad3a3dc2dd9f03dec02642dce1f194562e7f21820bc36ceb9f7b070d337fb45

Status: Downloaded newer image for oraclelinux:8

exec /bin/bash: no such file or directory```

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That didn't format right, but you should get the idea. It didn't work. And I don't have access to an ARM host to check my image.

Comment: Update your question, rather than leaving big chunks of output in comments. It's easier to read and makes the information more obvious to other people who are reading your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset`, it sets the handler for aarch64 binaries to:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-aarch64
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
flags:
offset 0
magic 7f454c460201010000000000000000000200b700
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

Unfortunately, CentOS 7 doesn't have the `-static` versions of these binaries:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64*
/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64
```

Fortunately, the `multiarch/qemu-user-static` container includes the necessary binaries in the image; you can copy onto your host like this:

```
$ docker run --rm  --entrypoint tar multiarch/qemu-user-static \
    -C /usr/bin -cf- . | tar -C /usr/bin -xf-
```

Now we have:

```
[root@localhost bin]# ls /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64*
/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64  /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64_be-static  /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
```

This gets us *so close*, but we need to mount the static binary into the image as described in the [docs for multiarch/qemu-user-static](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static#usage):

```
[root@localhost bin]# docker run --platform linux/arm64 --rm -v /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static:/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static  oraclelinux:8.5 uname -a
Linux 2d7e2e0ce6d7 3.10.0-1160.66.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 18 16:02:34 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

(Or you need to build the interpreter into the image.)

We need to mount `qemu-aarch64-static` inside the container on CentOS 7 because the kernel doesn't appear to support the `F` flag for `binfmt_misc` interpreters. The `F` flag means:

> **F - fix binary**
>
> The usual behaviour of binfmt_misc is to spawn the binary lazily when the misc format file is invoked. However, this doesn’t work very well in the face of mount namespaces and changeroots, so the F mode opens the binary as soon as the emulation is installed and uses the opened image to spawn the emulator, meaning it is always available once installed, regardless of how the environment changes.

(from the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html))

`multiarch/qemu-user-static` will set the `F` flag if you set
`--persistent yes` on the command line, but on CentOS 7 this fails with:

```
$ docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset
--persistent yes
...
Setting /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static as binfmt interpreter for aarch64
sh: write error: Invalid argument
```

---

With recent Fedora distributions (and probably others as well), you can simply install the `qemu-user-static` package and everything will Just Work (no need to use the `multiarch/qemu-user-static` image):

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 34 (Thirty Four)
$ rpm -q qemu-user-static
qemu-user-static-5.2.0-9.fc34.x86_64
$ uname -m
x86_64
$ docker run --platform linux/arm64 --rm oraclelinux:8.5 uname -a
Linux 6f04d17234f5 5.17.6-100.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 9 14:41:31 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

The `qemu-user-static` package installs all the `binfmt_misc`
registrations for you.

Comment: FWIW, on ArchLinux, there is `qemu-user-static-binfmt` to achive the same.

Comment: For debian there is `qemu-user-static` and `qemu-user-bindmt`. Idk if it alone worked as i've tried a lot different sources, but now i can run x86_64 containers on `aarch64` after installing `qemu-user-static.